# ReportViewer prompt for credentials when using viewer control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reportviewer, credentials

I have a MVC web application that uses the ReportViewer control on a web forms page to view reports and a separate code routine to export the same reports directly to PDF. The export to PDF code works well, but when I try to view the same report in the ReportViewer control using the same path/credentials, I am getting the windows prompt to login.

The export code does not use the ReportViewer server control but instead the Render method the Report class, so I think the problem is likely in there somewhere.

I have successfully deployed this same code on other web servers with success, so I suspect it has something to do with configuration or version of the report viewer control. I tried updating from the version i was using (ReportViewer version 10.0.0.0) to version 12.0.0.0, but the problem remained after the update.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after figuring out that it had nothing to do with the report viewer control but rather with my routing configuration. The clue was that after entering credentials, I was getting a 404 error. The page that is displaying the report viewer is a web forms page, so then I started looking into issues with running Web forms side-by-side with mvc and came across this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/Contents/Item/Display/107) which showed how to setup routes to execute .aspx web forms. After tweaking the route, the report viewer web form page come up and executed just fine.